# How do I position a div in a row into a bootstrap container correctly while maintaining responsive web design?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to align the content to the existing container above, however I am unable to successfully commit this as the container is located in a row because I wanted the file directory div on the left which pushes the container to the right of course.

Assigning a position: fixed; to the file directory div would fix the issue however it would not maintain the responsive web design which Bootstrap offers with its superior system.

[image]

As you can see the content is not in the right spot.

I have tried numerous things in css however none of these didn't feel right. For now I have tried playing with the col system of Bootstrap for a bearable outcome. Furthermore the image I provided of the website is in fact the result of this piece of code in case one wonders whether the image corresponds to the code.

```
<div class="container"><h2><i class="fas fa-archive" style="color: darkgoldenrod"></i> Archive Register({{ $files_total }})</h2></div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-between">
        <div class="file-list col-lg-2">
            <h3 class="ml-5"><i class="fas fa-file-alt" style="color: darkgoldenrod"></i> File list:</h3>
            <div class="file-list ml-5">
                <p>List</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content col-lg-9">
            content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We need [mcve] not your PHP

Comment: Well there you go, I improved it for ya :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="file-list col-lg-2">
```

change to

```
<div class="file-list col-lg-3">
```

your col need 1 more col as it is a 12-grid column.
matching it to the right column

```
<div class="content col-lg-9">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However this will only extend the file-list div. What I exactly want is the content to align with the container above it (see image).

Comment: does it fix the problem if you make the col-lg-9 to 10 rather? because you have space in the center.  can really see if its aligned or not im looking for the header "archive register", which is where im basing the alignment at.

Comment: Unfortunately not as the content will be located too much to the left which would not allign with the container above.

Answer (score 0):

This would be because you are using a container for the heading, which is based on a fixed with of the screen, and container fluid which is the full width on the screen.

You could change the heading container to something like this to align it with your content column? (Presuming you are using Bootstrap 4)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-9 offset-lg-9">
            <h2><i class="fas fa-archive" style="color: darkgoldenrod"></i> Archive Register({{ $files_total }})</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First and foremost, thanks for your answer! This is a solution however any other page on the website uses a .container which would make this page look "distorded", if you get what I mean. Either it would look inconsisent or it will be a lot of work editing all the other pages to the col format.